# How can I call a python script with arguments from within Processing?

Tags: python, json, processing

I have a `python` script which outputs a `JSON` when called with different arguments. I am looking for a way to call that script from within Processing and load the output using something like `loadJSONObject()`

The problem is that I don't know how to call the python script with arguments from within Processing.

Any tip will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @felipsmartins I'm sorry I don't have an example because I don't know if there is a way it can be done. That is the purpose of my question. Do you know how to call python with arguments from within Processing? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for the `open` function? https://processing.org/reference/open_.html

Comment: @JasonSperske Thanks, not sure if that will do it but I will definitely try if I can pass the output of the python to a String using Open() Thanks a lot. I let you know if it works so you can make it an answer.

Comment: Add a link to the `processing` library you are using. Is it this one? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/processing/

Comment: @matiasg No, I am using Processing the language https://processing.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, as pointed out in the comments, is to use [open](https://processing.org/reference/open_.html), and then load the file that generates the normal way.

Another -arguably much better- way is to not do this and to run your python script as services with a web interface instead, so that your python scripts sits listening on http://localhost:1234, for instance, and your Processing sketch can simply load a file "http://localhost:1234/somefile?input=whatever" and not even care what is actually generating the content.

The upside there is also that you can run your script *anywhere* that can be reached via URLs, and those things don't need to rely on python being available as an executable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. Your option is the best, actually I thought to myself something similar but I know how to do that with PHP I did not know I was able to do the same with python and send the parameters in the URL and make python read them. I will learn more about python as a web service.